# getting user info if WebAPI is authenticated based on Client Credentials

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

Before having Azure AD by web application and API were -

User enters id and password on app form -> user gets logged in (Asp.net Identity) -> with same credential, get token generated (grant_type=password) at WebAPI-> store this token as cookie to be used later on.

Now with Azure AD -

I have a scenario where I have to authenticate user using Azure AD. The webapi at Azure passes JWT containing logged in user information. From this information I'm extracting user email and forcing my web Application to log in user (Asp.net Identity).

Web App call WebAPI to get token, since I can't pass password so my token call changed to (grant_type=client_credentials). However, I loose information on individual user who logged to Web API. If I check context.user it points to unique client id instead of any user.

I know its messy, but the requirement was to use same applications for Azure AD authentication as well as on premise form authentication. Please suggest if there is any easier way to achieve this.

**Edit:** I'm using Owin oAuth

I'm using same application for both Form authentication and Azure AD. However recently had to add logging mechanism at web api level which is working for on-premise app which logs using userid/password. But it doesn't work if webapi issues token with client credentials. I tried to pass username as parameter while verifying client id (in ValidateClientAuthentication) and log on user. however webapi can't retain this user info.

Comment: It would help if I knew what protocols and technologies you are using. OpenIdConnect, OAuth? Katana / Asp.net core 1.0 / etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what I have done to fix my issue - Instead of assigning claimsIdentity for client I generated user identity. (_username is local variable which gets assigned value in "ValidateClientAuthentication" from the parameter. I understand this may not be ideal way, but now my application now works on Form Authentication as well as Azure AD using JWT tokens)

```
 public override async Task GrantClientCredentials(OAuthGrantClientCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(_userName);

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, null);

            context.Validated(ticket);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The client credential flow is used for the daemon apps or service to delegate the app to manipulate the resource. In this scenario, there is no user context information.

Based on my understanding, when we use Azure AD as the identity provider we use the OpenId connect protocol to acquire the id_token form Azure AD.  The OpenId connect also support **hybrid** flow to acquire the **authorization code** and **id_token** in the same request.

If you were developing with MVC with OWIN component, this flow is by default. We only need to acquire the access token with the authorization code(OAuth 2.0 code grant flow) return by Azure AD to call the Web API and this doesn’t require users sign-in again. And to acquire the token with authorization code we can add the notification like code below:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    //
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                    //
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }

            });
}

private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
{
        var code = context.Code;

        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));

        // If you create the redirectUri this way, it will contain a trailing slash.  
        // Make sure you've registered the same exact Uri in the Azure Portal (including the slash).
        Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));

        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, uri, credential, graphResourceId);
}
```

The full code sample to call the web API from web app you can refer [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect.git).